# laravel / Mongodb - How to insert new key/ value to an existing document

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have this document:

[image]

Now I want to add a new key / value to that document which id is : 34401

My key / value is like an array:

```
$data = [
    'id_project'            =>  $id_project, 
    'id_product'            =>  $product_id, 
    'link'                  =>  $link, 
    'id_product_competitor' =>  $id_competitor, 
    'link_competitor'       =>  ''
];
```

what I am doing is this:

```
$insert_to_mongodb = DB::connection('mongodb')
->collection( 'products_' . $id_project . '_' . $id_competitor )                
->insert($data);
```

Here this 'products_' . $id_project . '_' . $id_competitor is **products_1_23** as collection name.

After run this code Its inserting newly document but I want to add ths key/value to an existing document.

Answer (score 1):

I belive the better way is to create a model for the mongodb collection,
install Jenssegers\Mongodb using the command composer require jenssegers/mongodb, [reference link](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class ProductsModel extends Eloquent{

    /**
     * Connection name
     *
     */
    protected $connection   =   'mongodb';

    /**
     * Collection name
     * 
     */
    protected $collection   =   'products';


}
```

Now you can insert or update using the eloquent way

```
 ProductsModel::insert($data);

 ProductsModel::where('_id',$id)->update($data);
```

Comment: do you know how can I delete some specific key?

Comment: Ah, I need to use `unset` :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have soleve it by following way:

```
$insert_to_mongodb = DB::connection('mongodb')
->collection( 'products_' . $id_project . '_' . $id_competitor )
->where('id', (int) $product_id)
->update($data, ['upsert' => true]);
```